# Definition of a continuous Gabor frame

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, topological-groups

I am trying to understand the definition of a **Gabor frame** and would appreciate some clarification with terminology. Let us begin with the setup: Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group, and let $\widehat{G}$ be its Pontryganin dual. Let $\mu$ be a (left) Haar measure, denote the associated square integrable functions by $L^2(G)$ and let
$$
\pi:G \times \widehat{G} \to \mathcal{B}(L^2(G))
$$
a continuous group representation. Finally, let $\Delta \subseteq G \times \widehat{G}$ be a closed cocompact subgroup.

For some fixed element $g \in L^2(G)$, we say that $(\pi(z)g)_{z \in \Delta}$ is a **continuous Gabor frame** is it is **weakly measurable** and $\exists$ $C,D > 0$ such that
$$
C\|f\|^2 \leq \int_{\Delta}|\langle f,\pi(z),g\rangle|^2dz \leq D\|f\|^2,
$$
where the integral is **interpreted weakly**.

What do the highlighted terms **weakly measurable** and **interpreted weakly** mean? I know what a weakly measurable function from a measure space to a Banach space is, and I would guess that here **weakly measurable** means that the function
$$
\pi(-)g:\Delta \to \mathcal{B}(L^2(G))
$$
is weakly measurable. Is this correct? As for **interpreted weakly** I really have no idea what this means . . .